# Facebook Login - Do not require friends list

Tags: php, facebook

I'm currently scoping for just email on my Facebook login link

```
$params = array(
    'redirect_uri' => $redirect_url,
    'scope' => 'email'
);
```

But Facebook states that the user is providing access to their friend list. Users will not login because of this requirement.

Does anyone know how to turn it off?

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. By granting access to your application (even without specifying any permissions), some information is already made available to your app.

Check out the [documentation page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/public-profile-and-friend-list/) dealing with the basic permissions granted to an application:

> The public profile and friend list is the basic information available
> to an app. All other permissions and content must be explicitly asked
> for.
>
> When a user logs into your app and you request no additional
> permissions, **the app will have access to only the user's public
> profile and friend list.** By default, public profile includes the
> following properties:
>
> - id
> - name
> - first_name
> - last_name
> - link
> - username
> - gender
> - locale
> - age_range
> - Other [public information](https://www.facebook.com/about/privacy/your-info#public-info)

There is no way to turn it off and every single application that you install will display this warning/alert (that you are providing the application access to this data).

Comment: Read that and should have mentioned it in my question. Surprised this is a default.